# Projective representation in Weinberg's QFT book

Tags: quantum-field-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

Weinberg's QFT vol 1 has excellent discussion on symmetries and projective representations. Because physical states are represented by rays in the Hilbert space, symmetries are realized as projective representations
\begin{align}
 U(g_1) U(g_2) = e^{\phi(g_1,g_2)} U(g_1g_2)
\end{align}
where $g$'s are group elements and $U$'s are (anti)unitary operators in the Hilbert space. For Lie groups, there are two sources for the nontrivial phase $\phi(g_1,g_2)$, the central charges in the Lie algebra, and the non-trivial topology of the group. It's shown in the book that the Poincare group is essentially central-charge-free and the $SO^+(3,1)$ subgroup is doubly covered by the simply-connected group $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ (no nontrivial topology in the boost components). Therefore, for the Poincare group we have
\begin{align}
 U(g_1) U(g_2) = \pm U(g_1g_2)
\end{align}
with the superselection rule $+$ for Bosons (no minus sign for a $2\pi$ rotation), and $-$ for Fermions (minus sign for a $2\pi$ rotation). Alternatively, we can change the point of view and take the covering group $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ as the symmetry group, then the representation is no longer projective, we simply have
\begin{align}
 U(g_1) U(g_2) = U(g_1g_2)
\end{align}
In Weinberg's book, lots of discussion before section 2.7 (on projective representation) assumes the representation is regular and uses the equation above explicitly. I'd assume he takes the point of view that the symmetry group is $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ (times the boost components). Then in defining a single particle state with general momentum a term $U(L(p))$ is ambiguous, since there are two $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ elements corresponding to the standard boost $L(p)$. Equally confusing is the definition of space inversion and time reversal operators
\begin{align}
 P U(\Lambda,a) P^{-1} = U(\mathcal{P}\Lambda\mathcal{P}^{-1},\mathcal{P}a) \\
 T U(\Lambda,a) T^{-1} = U(\mathcal{T}\Lambda\mathcal{T}^{-1},\mathcal{T}a)
\end{align}
we either think the symmetry group is $SO^+(1,3)$ and a phase for projective representation is needed on the right hand side, or we think the symmetry group is $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $U(\Lambda,a)$ is ambiguous. Should we view $U(L(p))$ as an operator for an element in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ times boosts obtained by lifting a standard path from the identity to $L(p)$ in the Poincare group? Should the defining equations of $P,T$ operators be understood with path-lifting as well?